# aws appsync offline : getting error Variable id was not provided

Tags: swift, offline, aws-appsync

I am using AWS AppSync for mobile development (iOS) for offline/Online Capabilities

I am trying to save data in offline mode. But I am getting error "Variable id was not provided/ Missing value"

When app comes to online it automatically syncing to DynamoDB but the issue is only in offline mode unable to fetch saved record

Here is the code using in the application

`

```
    let userObjInput = userObjectInput(id: "id", firstName: "firstname", lastName: "lastName")

    let CategoryInputs = CreateUserCategoryInput(categoryName: "categoryValue" , user: userObjInput)

    let mutation =  CategoryMutation(input: CategoryInputs)

    appSyncClient?.perform(mutation: mutation, queue: .main, optimisticUpdate: { (transaction) in

            do {
                let selectionSets = try transaction?.read(query: query)
                try transaction?.update(query: GetUserCategoriesOfUserQuery(id: "id")) { (data: inout GetUserCategoriesOfUserQuery.Data) in
                  data.getAllCategoriesForUser?.append(GetUserCategoriesOfUserQuery.Data.GetAllCategoriesForUser?.init(GetUserCategoriesOfUserQuery.Data.GetAllCategoriesForUser.init(id: (UUID().uuidString), categoryName: CategoryInputs.categoryName!, isDeleted: false, user: GetUserCategoriesOfUserQuery.Data.GetAllCategoriesForUser.User?.init(GetUserCategoriesOfUserQuery.Data.GetAllCategoriesForUser.User.init(id: userObjInput.id!, firstName: userObjInput.firstName!, lastName: userObjInput.lastName!)))))
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
    }, conflictResolutionBlock: nil, resultHandler: { (result, error) in

        if error == nil {
            fetchCategories()

        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })`
```

Comment: How are you initializing your appsync configuration? Are you using "id" as your cache key?

Does the optimistic write mentioned in the sample app here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-events-starter-ios/blob/master/EventsApp/AddEventViewController.swift#L49 work for you? Could you follow similar patter for your use-case?

Comment: I am following the same pattern and using id as cache. Problem with aws sdk was if we use parameters in get query it fails to fetch records. I posted question and example to support 2 months back. They are still investigating the problem .

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I think I have the same problem.

Comment: No response from aws support. I am fetching all the records and applying filters

Comment: This bug is already fixed in new release of iOS AppSync SDK `2.6.22`

Answer (score 0):

For those who have problem with `optimistic UI missing value`. I've found one trick to temporary solve the issue by passing parameter using `Custom Request Header` from client app.
Before, your query would look like this  `allDiaries(author: String): [Diary]`

Just change it to => `allDiaries: [Diary]`

So your `request mapping` would look like below:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
    "filter" : {
        "expression" : "author = :author",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":author" : { "S" : "$context.request.headers.author" }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [How to pass AWS AppSync custom request header in iOS client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932849/how-to-pass-aws-appsync-custom-request-header-in-ios-client/51950574#51950574)

Hope it is useful! Goodluck :)